# NIFI secured cluster : Setup 2 nodes but only 1 node detected (Apache Nifi 1.11.4)

Tags: java, hadoop, etl, apache-nifi

I need to setup secured nifi cluster using 2 nodes. **Im using latest version of nifi : 1.11.4**

I thought I successfully build the cluster, because the UI **successfully open for both the https url**, also if I do something (ex: put new processor) in one of them, the other is successfully sync.
But suddenly I realized the total node detected only 1!
Where is the other one???
Here is the prove:

[both webs Successfully open and sync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXJ0Y.png)

I've setup all the conf (authorizers.xml, nifi.properties, zookeeper, statemanagement, ssl, etc) properly enough.

You can check the conf and logs on below links:

**NODE 1 conf - bihdpapp399**

[bihdpapp399](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cGtfwap_Xq_nGYgWKGZSNFzxeTANVCgT/view?usp=sharing)

**NODE 2 conf - bihdpapp394**

[bihdpapp394](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MMYSG55jvn7Yqxd044oR27AVGBMe-R41/view?usp=sharing)

Btw, as you know Im using 2 nodes, but based on the logs the other node doesnt want to vote the election although I already set the max election conf for both nodes = 2, I also have tried to increase the election time from 1m to 5m, but still no vote from the other node:

```
2020-06-25 12:08:16,909 INFO [main] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Requested by cluster coordinator to retry connection in 5 seconds with explanation: Cluster is still voting on which Flow is the correct flow for the cluster. Election will complete in 59 seconds or after 1 more vote is cast, whichever occurs first.
2020-06-25 12:08:22,012 INFO [main] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Requested by cluster coordinator to retry connection in 5 seconds with explanation: Cluster is still voting on which Flow is the correct flow for the cluster. Election will complete in 54 seconds or after 1 more vote is cast, whichever occurs first.
2020-06-25 12:08:27,116 INFO [main] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Requested by cluster coordinator to retry connection in 5 seconds with explanation: Cluster is still voting on which Flow is the correct flow for the cluster. Election will complete in 49 seconds or after 1 more vote is cast, whichever occurs first.
2020-06-25 12:08:32,216 INFO [main] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Requested by cluster coordinator to retry connection in 5 seconds with explanation: Cluster is still voting on which Flow is the correct flow for the cluster. Election will complete in 44 seconds or after 1 more vote is cast, whichever occurs first.
2020-06-25 12:08:37,317 INFO [main] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Requested by cluster coordinator to retry connection in 5 seconds with explanation: Cluster is still voting on which Flow is the correct flow for the cluster. Election will complete in 39 seconds or after 1 more vote is cast, whichever occurs first.
2020-06-25 12:08:42,418 INFO [main] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Requested by cluster coordinator to retry connection in 5 seconds with explanation: Cluster is still voting on which Flow is the correct flow for the cluster. Election will complete in 34 seconds or after 1 more vote is cast, whichever occurs first.
```

Comment: I think you have deployed two single node clusters (i.e. two different clusters, each with one node). The configurations need to be such that they point to the same ZooKeeper cluster and register as members of the same cluster.

Comment: Hi @Andy thanks for your response, I already adjust the same zookeeper configuration for each node, also when I see the Cluster info from the main menu, from both of them it only show one same node, so we can make sure its in the same cluster, right?
for more details you can download it from above. Please help bro, Ive been stuck at this for about 1 week :'(

Answer (score 1):

The $NIFI_Directory/state/local folder stores the state of the cluster and utilizes the same even after adding a node. Delete or rename the state folder and restart nifi cluster. This helped me to solve the issue.